# Back button not displayed due to existing left navbar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a view which has a left navigation bar button. Because of this button, the 'native' back button is not displayed.

How do I programmatically remove the custom navigation bar button to make room for the native back button? (I am using IOS 7)

Setting it to nil in viewDidLoad doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How do you set it to nil? Code, please.

Comment: you can set 'leftItemsSupplementBackButton' on the 'UINavigationItem' so show both the back button AND the leftBarButton simultaneously. If you want to only show the back button, reset the 'leftBarButtonItem' to nil. Do not set the 'backButtonItem' to nil.

Comment: Awesome @Cabus, solved!
`[self.navigationItem setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton:YES];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`